# Cross Calculations Between Two Fields

Tags: javascript

I have two fields 'value_figure' and 'value_btc' and I want to do cross calculations.

1. When a figure is in 'value_figure' e.g 4800, it will be divided by the price of the product. e.g 4000000 and it will show the result lets say 0.0012 in 'value_btc' field.
2. When a decimal number is in 'value_btc' e.g 0.0012, it will be multiplied by the price of the product. e.g 4000000 and it will show the result lets say 4800 in 'value_figure' field.

```
  <input class="form-control" id="id_value_figure" name="value_figure" title="" type="number" required />

   <input class="form-control" id="id_value_btc" name="value_btc" title="" type="text" required />
```

How do I go about this in javascript? I'm a noob when it comes to this.

Comment: bind to `change` event on those inputs

Comment: How? I don't know how to write a javascript code. I google for solutions, didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get reference to your two elements and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to hook up the `change` event. Beyond that its some simple arithmetic.

```js
window.onload = function(){
   var figure = document.getElementById("id_value_figure");
   var btc = document.getElementById("id_value_btc");
   var price = 4000000 ;

   figure.addEventListener('change',function(){
      var val = parseInt(this.value,10);
      btc.value = val / price;
   });
   
   btc.addEventListener('change',function(){
      var val = parseFloat(this.value);
      figure.value = val * price;
   });
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="id_value_figure" name="value_figure" title="" type="number" required />

<input class="form-control" id="id_value_btc" name="value_btc" title="" type="text" required />
```

Comment: Just asking, since each of the two textboxes have a "change" event listener which ends up altering value of the other one, would they not keep firing the function attached to the listener ? would it be better to have them do this on a keyup event ? or does changing values through JS not fire the change event ?

Comment: @kshishoo Changes from javascript dont fire that event.

Comment: thanks @jamiec. You rock.  BTW: How do I enforce that the value input in the value_btc field is decimal?

Comment: @YoYo you can make it `type="number"` to help the user, but that doesnt enforce the type of number. You need to validate the entry and show an appropriate message if the user enters an incorrect value. There are literally thousands of online articles about javascript validation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var price = 4000000 // Your value
    function btcConvert(valNum) {
      valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
      document.getElementById("id_value_figure").value = (valNum*price);
    }
    
    function figConvert(valNum) {
      valNum = parseFloat(valNum);
      document.getElementById("id_value_btc").value = (valNum / price);
    }
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="id_value_figure" name="value_figure" title="" type="number" oninput="figConvert(this.value)" onchange="figConvert(this.value)" required />

<input class="form-control" id="id_value_btc" name="value_btc" title="" type="number" oninput="btcConvert(this.value)" onchange="btcConvert(this.value)" required />
```